# Change css of div, if specific child div's are active

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have a class with 4 different columns.

```
div class="mainContent">
        <div class="left-Col-1" *ngIf="data-1">
        </div>
        <div class="left-Col-2" *ngIf="!data-1">
        </div>
        <div class="right-Col-1" *ngIf="data-2">
        </div>
        <div class="right-Col-2" *ngIf="!data-2">
        </div>
</div>
```

Basicly i created a flexbox where i show two colums. If there's no data-1 in the first column i show div-right-2, and the same happens when theres no data-2, where i show div-left-2. If they both have data i show div-left-1 and div-right-1.
My css looks like this:

```
.mainContent > *:nth-child(1){
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 flex-basis: 70%;
 padding: 0;
}
.mainContent > *:nth-child(2){
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 flex-basis: 30%;
 padding: 0;
}
```

The problem is that i want to change flex-basis to 50% in both div's if there is no data loaded (if first div is "left-div-2" and the second div "right-div-2"). Is that possible only using css or do i need to write some fucntion on typescript?

Ty for your help.

Comment: Have you tried placing .mainContent > * { flex-basis: 50%; }  at the top?

Comment: It has the same effect. The problem is that i want the same div to have different basis, depending on the other active div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be confusing yourself by using an odd/even selector that you don't understand.  Your selector splits your divs into odd and even children and the only difference is the flex-basis is 70% for the odd ones and 30% for the even.  With the change you are describing you have 3 different values for 4 different classes, so don't use the odd even thing.  Angular is going to remove two of those divs based on the content of data-1 anyway.

Since you are using four different classes for your four divs you might as well use them to specify what flex-basis you want for each.  See if you can understand what this css does.

```
.mainContent{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0;
}

.mainContent .left-Col-1{
    flex-basis: 70%;
}
.mainContent .right-Col-1{
    flex-basis: 30%;
}
.mainContent .left-Col-2, .mainContent .right-Col-2{
    flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

The best would probably be to use classes that are more descriptive like full/empty and primary/secondary.  That would make your code more clear and easy to manage.

Comment: I could do that but it doesnt do what i want. I wanna define flex-basis based on the div's that are active. If right-Col-1, and left-Col-2 is active, the flex basis of right-col-1 is gonna be 70% and the other 30%. So the same div can have different percentages based on the other active div.